# Can't find Android Emulator in SDK tools on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't find the AVD in Android Studio, so I tried to install Android Emulator by going to SDK tools. However I can't find Android Emulator in SDK tools.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you just can't find it in the Studio, go to the device section (where there is "No Devices" or name of your device) and choose AVD Manager. There is no need for downloading emulator separately if you have a new release of Android Studio. If you have some problem with the Studio please describe more details

[screenshot of device section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mHG7.png)